# Dynamically change in the configuration of aws_elasticache_replication_group in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, terraform, amazon-elasticache

I am configuring elasticache cluster using terraform and everything works fine!
Now my requirenment is that i want to do the dynamic configuration inside resource for **cluster-mode**.

Below is my common code..

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "elasticache_redis_cluster" {
  replication_group_id          = "cache"
  engine_version                = "${var.engine_version}"
  node_type                     = "${var.node_type}"
  port                          = "${var.elasticache_port}"
  parameter_group_name          = "${var.param_group_name}"
  security_group_ids            = ["${aws_sg.id}"]
  subnet_group_name             = "${aws_elasticache_subnet_group.subnet_group.id}"
}
```

Now i want to perform following operation based on the passed parameter.

```
  if (${var.cluster_mode == "enable") {
        automatic_failover_enabled    = true  
        cluster_mode { 
           replicas_per_node_group     = 1 
           num_node_groups             = 1
        }
  }
  else {
        number_cache_clusters = 2
  }
```

Above code based on matched condition should be appended inside the configuration of the cluster.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Terraform Conditionals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals) only support ternary assignment of values.

Eg, they can only be in the form of:

```
resource "cool_thing" "my_resource" {
    is_prod_thing = "${var.env == "production" ? true : false}"
}
```

Values returned from the ternary operation must be the same type, and there is no direct way to internally switch between differing resource configurations.

A possible workaround is to use the `count` [Meta-Parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count) to create zero or more resources based on a variable value:

```
variable "cluster_mode" {
  default = "enable"
}

locals {
  cluster_count = "${var.cluster_mode == "enable" ? 1 : 0}"
  non_cluster_count = "${var.cluster_mode == "enable" ? 0 : 1}"
} 

resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "elasticache_redis_cluster" {
  # Configuration for clustered nodes
  count = "${local.cluster_count}"
}

resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "elasticache_redis_non_cluster" {
  # Configuration for non-clustered nodes
  count = "${local.non_cluster_count}"
}
```

This way you can describe both configurations of the resource that might be needed, and switch which one is created based on the value of `cluster_mode`.